# Computing days to renew

Tags: php, mysql, date

Let's say I have an auction database - the data I save is the auction's id and its begin time (as an int in the meaning of Unix Time).
Each auction is renewed (internally, not depending on me) after each 30 days and I'd like to know using MySQL how many days there are 'till the next renew.

In PHP I used the following code I wrote:

```
public static function computeDaysToRenew($dateUnix) {
    $dateToday = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    $dateRenew = new DateTime();
    $dateRenew->setTimestamp($dateUnix)->modify('+30 days');

    while ($dateRenew->getTimestamp() < $dateToday->getTimestamp()) {
        $dateRenew->modify('+30 days');
    }

    return (int) $dateRenew->diff($dateToday)->format('%d');
}
```

But being honest, I don't even know how to approach this problem in MySQL - I've read about `interval` but I can't see a solution.

Comment: I think what you're trying to ask is how to query a MySQL database and add a computed column to the result set. But before you ask that here, you should google a bit. If you still have a question, come back and show us the query you're using and ask us for help with that.

Comment: The problem is that I can use `SELECT date_add(date_begin, interval +30 days) AS date_renew FROM (...)` but what if that begin date is like 100 days long? It should round to the next 30 days and that's the problem I'm facing with.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 30 - (DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_begin) % 30) AS days_left;
```

[`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) returns the difference in days between the dates, the [modulus operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_mod) returns the remainder of the division operation.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),'2001-01-31 00:00:00') AS DaysSinceLastRenew;

SELECT 30 - DATEDIFF(NOW(),'2001-01-31 00:00:00') % 30  AS DaysToNextRenew;



SELECT DATE_ADD('2001-01-31 00:00:00', INTERVAL 30 DAY);


SELECT DATE_ADD( FIELDNAME, INTERVAL 30 DAY) FROM yourtable;
```